# Large standard error of intercept and low overdispersion parameter from negative binomial hurdle model using glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-model, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am running hurdle models on some count data using the R package glmmTMB. For one of my models, I tried the "truncated_nbinom1" family, but this model fails to converge. When I use the family "truncated_nbinom2", I get a very low intercept value with a large standard error in the conditional part of the model. I also get a very low overdispersion parameter.

```
> hurdle.nb1 <- glmmTMB(COUNT ~ mamm_att_scaled + (1|COUNTRY1),
+                              zi = ~.,
+                              europe, family = "truncated_nbinom1") 
Error in optimHess(par.fixed, obj$fn, obj$gr) : 
  gradient in optim evaluated to length 1 not 7


> hurdle.nb2 <- glmmTMB(COUNT ~ mamm_att_scaled + (1|COUNTRY1),
+                              zi = ~.,
+                              europe, family = "truncated_nbinom2") 

> summary(hurdle.nb2) 
 Family: truncated_nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          COUNT ~ mamm_att_scaled + (1 | COUNTRY1)
Zero inflation:         ~.
Data: europe

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  3113.1   3168.5  -1549.6   3099.1    20122 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 COUNTRY1 (Intercept) 1.096    1.047   
Number of obs: 20129, groups:  COUNTRY1, 40

Zero-inflation model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 COUNTRY1 (Intercept) 2.255    1.502   
Number of obs: 20129, groups:  COUNTRY1, 40

Overdispersion parameter for truncated_nbinom2 family (): 1.21e-08 

Conditional model:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      -18.2359  2361.8098  -0.008    0.994
mamm_att_scaled    0.2083     0.2494   0.835    0.404

Zero-inflation model:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       4.4169     0.2840  15.554  < 2e-16 ***
mamm_att_scaled  -0.6549     0.1522  -4.302 1.69e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I ran regular (i.e. no zero-inflation) negative binomial models and hurdle poisson models but AIC suggests the hurdle negative binomial model is the better fit. However, I'm not sure how to interpret these results and whether it suggests the model is, in fact, not a good fit for the data? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: it's a bit hard to read from your output. If i got it correct, you have a lot of zeros in your data? So going by the second model, the intercept for zero inflation part is 4.41.. which translates to about 99% zeros?

Comment: Yes there are lots of zeros, about 98.6% in this dataset. The counts range from 0-12.

Comment: yeah..looking at the above, you are left with around 400 non-zero..  might not need a negative binomial... if you say it's from 0-12. The low dispersion means there's no extra poisson variance. you can try a zero inflated poisson. The intercept, there's nothing much you can do..

Comment: you have so many zeros, how certain are you of the true mean? also is there reason to believe the zero counts are dependent on mamm_att_scaled ? If not you fit a model zi = ~ 1 then, this might help the intercept in the fixed effect